# Angular5: Hide ag-gird rows based on condition

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have the below response from the service, when ever the `flag` is true I have to hide the whole row (total 20 columns I have) else show it. How can I achieve this in ag-grid?

```
data = {
    name: "A",
    flag: true
   },
   {
    name: "B",
    flag: false
   },
   {
    name: "C",
    flag: false
   }
```

I did try the `useExternalFilter` like below and then I got stuck as to how to use this `useExternalFilter` further. Can any one please guide me through.

```
this.filterOptions = {
  useExternalFilter: true
};

this.gridOptions = {
  filterOptions:  this.filterOptions
 };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what you want is this:

```
this.gridOptions = {
  // is always present, so return true
  isExternalFilterPresent: function() { 
    return true; 
  },

  // return true if flag=true
  doesExternalFilterPass: function(rowNode) { 
    return rowNode.data.flag; 
  }
};
```

see [ag-Grid Docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-external/) for more details

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to do this is, filter your data first based on the flag value

```
const filteredData = this.data.filter(item => !item.flag);
```

Then set this filteredData as grid data

```
this.gridOptions.setRowData(this.filteredData);
```

Hope this will do the needful

Answer (score 0):

Even though we can use `api.setRowData(newData)` to explicitly update/remove your data, this method essentially hard resets your entire grid. According to the [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/#bulk-method-1-row-data-normal), this results in the following:

> the grid discards all previous selections and filters, and completely
>   overwrites the old data with the new. This was the first way the grid
>   worked and is the most 'brute force' way.

As such, I would recommend you to use `transaction.remove` instead. According to the [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/#removing-rows), you can either supply the `rowNodeId` to remove the rows, or we can remove the rows by using the rows based on object reference.

This method is preferred, as

> The grid keeps all active sorting, grouping and filtering, including
>   updating to reflect the changes in the data should the sorting,
>   grouping or filtering be impacted.

First, we can get the list of objects that need to be removed. Then, we use `api.updateRowData(transaction)` to carry out the transaction to update the row data such that those rows will be removed.

```
const removeData = this.data.filter(item => item.flag);
this.gridApi.updateRowData({ remove: removeData });
```

I have created a [working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/aozZ2sVc50gB8Jhwul2o?p=preview) to illustrate the above behaviour.

Comment: @DilaniAlwis Your answer is 100% correct :) I am just providing an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter more dynamically, you can use bind method

```
this.gridOptions = {
  // is always present, so return true
  isExternalFilterPresent: function() { 
    return true;
  }
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.gridOptions.doesExternalFilterPass = this.isVisible.bind(this)
}

isVisible(rowNode): boolean {
  // Write your logic. You can use rowNode and all component valiables.
}
```